# Newbie Spirit not trying alternatives

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am having trouble getting Spirit to try alternatives. I am new to Spirit and probably doing something grossly wrong, so I apologize for dragging down the SNR but any help is appreciated:

I am using a grammar like the following to match "character classes"

```
'[' >> *(~ascii::char_("-]^") | (ascii::char_ >> '-' >>ascii::char_)) >> ']'
```

This matches `[abc]` but not `[a-c]`. If I remove the first alternative, then `[a-c]` matches. Shouldn't Spirit try the second alternative when the first fails?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that the first alternative *does* match -- it just doesn't match what you want it to.  As written, your parser matches a sequence of 3 thing, with the middle one being a repeated pattern having an alternative in it.

```
   '['                   // single char match
>> *(~ascii::char_("-]^") | (ascii::char_ >> '-' >>ascii::char_))  // complex pattern
>> ']'                   // single char match
```

So lets look at what happens when you try to match `[a-c]`.  First, you match the pattern `'['`, which succeeds and leaves `a-c]`.  So then it looks at the complex pattern, which it tries to match 0 or more times.  With in that `*` repeat, it first tries `~ascii::char_("-]^")`, which matches `a`, so success leaving `-c]`.  It then repeats, trying to match that pattern again, which fails (`-` doesn't match), so it tries the second alternative where `ascii::char` matches `-`, but `'-'` does not match `c`, so it fails.  So the end of the `*` match it has matched the single character `a`.  Finally, it tries to match `']'` which fails against the `-`, so the overall match fails.

Reading the above (if you can make sense of it) should make it clear what you need to do -- you need it to try the range match BEFORE it tries the single char match within the `*` loop:

```
'[' >> *((ascii::char_ >> '-' >>ascii::char_) | ~ascii::char_("-]^")) >> ']'
```

Now it should match both `[abc]` and `[a-c]`, as well as things like `[a-cmx-z]`.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer. I've written many recursive descent parsers by hand, and when I find myself painted into the corner, I backtrack to where I could have taken a different branch of an alternation. It looks like Antlr also is willing to back up on this example and find a match. Is there any way to tell Spirit to keep trying the way Antlr does?

Comment: boost:spirit uses a PEG parser, which is strictly ordered and eager.  Antlr uses an LL parser, which is completely different.  The 'backtracking' in a PEG parser is only to the points at the `|` alternatives and not to other points.